# Concerning dividends and expense ratios

Tags: dividends

I've been searching through the myriad of questions/answers to this. I'm comparing 2 similar ETFs, one with a yield of 8.4% and expense ratio of 0.35%, and the other has a yield of 10.0% and expense ration of 0.94%.

From what I've gathered the expense has already been deducted from the asset before my dividend is computed, is that right?

So if my div. yield is 10%, and everything goes as planned, my dividends should total out right close to 10% at the end of the year.?  Or 8.4% for the other fund?  For some reason, this seems naive on my part.

Comment: Which ETFs are you comparing?

Answer (score 2):

Dividend yield is calculated from *past* dividends relative to the NAV at the time of the dividend. Fees are accrued continuously, so they do not appear all at once.

So *effectively* the dividend yield is calculated *after* fees are accounted for.

Also, dividends are not *guaranteed*, so you should not *expect* to get exactly 10% in dividends over the next year - the companies it holds may pay more or less dividends depending on their performance and the economy overall.

If you are looking for long-term growth, then the dividend is not relevant since the value of the ETF drops by the amount of the dividend when it is paid. If you reinvest the dividend you will own the same amount of the ETF as if you did not receive any dividend.

If you're looking for the highest cash return, then you should probably go with the higher yield ETF (assuming the overall return rates are close) - the fee difference is not meaningful compared to the dividend.

There is usually a "growth of $1,000" chart or something similar for both ETFs that will show you which has had better growth in the recent past *assuming you reinvest the dividends in each fund*. Most funds also have a table that shows total return (price + dividend) over the past 1, 3, and 5 years.

Those do not *guarantee* that the performance will continue, but if they are similar funds in terms of their investments (same sector, company size, etc.) it can tell you if one has been managed better.

Comment: If you are looking for the best return, start by looking for the funds with the lowest fees, which generally means index funds. It is surprisingly difficult for a human-managed mutual fund to outperform a computer-managed fund enough to more than cover the additional cost; cf "the Buffett bet."